# html2canvas cors error while fetching images from external domain

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to export a react component into a PDF
The steps I took are

- Converting the component to an Image using html2canvas
- creating a pdf
- attaching the image to the pdf

The component has some images whose URL's I get from calling their API and the src of image is an external domain url
html2canvas is throwing cors error for the external domain images

Below is the img element in html

here's the code block for conversion

`html2canvas(containerDiv, { allowTaint: false, useCORS: true, logging: true, }) .then(function (canvas) { const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, width, height); pdf.save(`${companyName}.pdf`); }) .catch((err) => console.log(err));`

Already tried methods:

1. setting crossorigin to true or anonymous
2. base64 conversion of the url and addding it to image src
3. adding random querystring to the image src
4. AllowTaint to true in the hmtl2canvas options (not working)

If any quick workarounds are possible

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend switching to [modern-screenshot](https://github.com/qq15725/modern-screenshot), it's more lightweight and provides better output quality, especially without the need of setting up a proxy server - [reference](https://github.com/qq15725/modern-screenshot/issues/3). Otherwise, if you prefer sticking to the html2canvas solution, you'd need to set up a proxy server (here's an [example](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs) by the lib author himself), get the server's URL and use it as:

```js
html2canvas(element, {
  allowTaint: true,
  useCORS: true,
  proxy: <server_url>
}).then(canvas => { ... });
```

Hope this helps.