How to Capture a Screenshot of a Cross-Origin Iframe in a Laravel App
I am developing a Laravel application that includes a feature to display 360-degree virtual tours. These tours are loaded into iframes and can be hosted on an AWS S3 bucket or another storage solution. The tours are HTML and JavaScript-based projects that showcase interactive 360-degree views.
I want to add a functionality where users can click a "Comment" button outside the iframe, which opens a sidebar with the current iframe view at the top and an "Add Comment" box below. When the user saves a comment, I need to capture a screenshot of the current iframe view and save it along with the comment.
The problem: I am running into cross-origin restrictions that prevent me from capturing a screenshot of the iframe content.
What I've Tried:

Using libraries like html2canvas to capture the screenshot, but it doesn't work due to cross-origin policies.
Investigating CORS settings, but I do not have control over the iframe content to modify headers.
Considering server-side rendering with headless browsers, but I'm unsure how to integrate it with my current setup.

Questions:

how can I capture screenshots of cross-origin iframes securely and legally.


I think this is not an APS Viewer-specific issue. The author of html2canvas has mentioned this in its README.

It does not require any rendering from the server, as the whole image
is created on the client's browser. However, as it is heavily
dependent on the browser, this library is not suitable to be used in
nodejs. It doesn't magically circumvent any browser content policy
restrictions either, so rendering cross-origin content will require a
proxy to get the content to the same origin.

So, you must set up a proxy server to resolve this issue. Here is an similar request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75418135
